# (Unity)How to pass variables, that are variable without a bunch of If Else Statements

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```c#
for (int m = 0; m < materialObjects.Length; m++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < materialModifiers.Count; i++)
                {
                    if(materialModifiers[i].valueType == LittleSubstanceModifier.ValueType.Float)
                    {
                        if (materialModifiers[i].valueFloat[0] != materialModifiers[i].oldValueFloat[0])
                        {
                            materialObjects[m].material.SetFloat(materialModifiers[i].identifier, materialModifiers[i].valueFloat[0]);
                            materialModifiers[i].valueFloat = materialModifiers[i].oldValueFloat;
                        }

                    }
                    else if (materialModifiers[i].valueType == LittleSubstanceModifier.ValueType.Float2 || materialModifiers[i].valueType == LittleSubstanceModifier.ValueType.Float3 || materialModifiers[i].valueType == LittleSubstanceModifier.ValueType.Float4)
                    {
                        if (materialModifiers[i].valueFloat != materialModifiers[i].oldValueFloat)
                        {
                            materialObjects[m].material.SetFloatArray(materialModifiers[i].identifier, materialModifiers[i].valueFloat);
                            materialModifiers[i].valueFloat = materialModifiers[i].oldValueFloat;
                        }
                    }                   
                    else if (materialModifiers[i].valueType == LittleSubstanceModifier.ValueType.Int)
                    {
                        if (materialModifiers[i].valueInt != materialModifiers[i].oldValueInt)
                        {
                            materialObjects[m].material.SetInt(materialModifiers[i].identifier, materialModifiers[i].valueInt[0]);
                            materialModifiers[i].valueFloat = materialModifiers[i].oldValueFloat;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (materialModifiers[i].valueType == LittleSubstanceModifier.ValueType.Int2 || materialModifiers[i].valueType == LittleSubstanceModifier.ValueType.Int3 || materialModifiers[i].valueType == LittleSubstanceModifier.ValueType.Int4)
                    {

                    }
                    else if (materialModifiers[i].valueType == LittleSubstanceModifier.ValueType.Bool)
                    {

                    }
                    else if (materialModifiers[i].valueType == LittleSubstanceModifier.ValueType.ColorField)
                    {

                    }
                    else if (materialModifiers[i].valueType == LittleSubstanceModifier.ValueType.Vector2)
                    {

                    }
                    else if (materialModifiers[i].valueType == LittleSubstanceModifier.ValueType.Vector3)
                    {

                    }
                    else if (materialModifiers[i].valueType == LittleSubstanceModifier.ValueType.Vector4)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
```

I'm making a tool right now, and the user is able to pick a variable type that the user can edit in the inspector window.

To pick the variable I'm using an Enum, but then to check which type of variable they chose, I'm using a bunch of Else Ifs. Now to pick the variable, its ok doing it with Else If, but when it comes time to changing the value I can't be doing 10 else ifs every time they add a letter, or change a number.

So my question, how can I pass the variable type that is selected, without finding out what they chose without a bunch of else ifs? It would be nice if I could use var, but it is being changed from another script.

Sorry for the long sloppy post, I really don't know what to call this and how to ask.

Edit: Here is my code, what would be a better way of doing this?

Edit2: Response to Robyn - I just wrote that code for an example, its basically the only way I would know how to do this. Sorry, I will try to explain as best I can.
In the image I posted, there is the Identifier text box, which has opacity in it.
Then the drop down with all the variable types. Then it has a text box. You hit the button add Mod, and a row of those pops up. You pick either your variable type, put in the materials identifier (example opacity). So to change opacity it needs to be a float. So when you change the float boxes value, it will change the materials opacity.
I basically need a value, that can be used as a float, int, bool, etc...
I've never used Switch or Case, so I don't really know what it does exactly. But I will look it up try! So Thanks.
I just uploaded 2 more images trying to visually explain it a little better.

[image: Tool]

[image: Code]

Comment: Your question is way too broad. You need to try _something_, and if you have some _specific_ trouble, post a question that includes a good [mcve] showing exactly what you tried, and explain precisely what that code does, what you want it to do instead, and what part of the problem you can't solve yourself. Based on your vague description, I will suggest polymorphism, i.e. a type hierarchy where a base abstract type (like an interface) describes what the editor needs, and then concrete implementations handle user input and display.

Comment: Really sorry, don't know what I want to do is called.
I just added the code, maybe that will help. I just need a better way to do this.

Comment: You could try using factory pattern. This way you describe the logic in the object that is passed into the factory. It is the pattern I use when if else logic becomes more difficult to manage. http://www.dofactory.com/net/factory-method-design-pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Switch and Foreach statements instead of If and For statements to make that code a little easier to read, to something like this:

```
foreach (var materialObject in materialObjects)
{
    foreach (var materialModifier in materialModifiers)
    {
        switch (materialModifier.valueType)
        {
            case LittleSubstanceModifier.ValueType.Float:
                if (materialModifier.valueFloat[0] != materialModifier.oldValueFloat[0])
                {
                     materialObject.material.SetFloat(materialModifier.identifier, materialModifier.valueFloat[0]);
                     materialModifier.valueFloat = materialModifier.oldValueFloat;
                }
                break;
            case LittleSubstanceModifier.ValueType.Float2:
            case LittleSubstanceModifier.ValueType.Float3:
            case LittleSubstanceModifier.ValueType.Float4:
                if (materialModifier.valueFloat != materialModifier.oldValueFloat)
                {
                    materialObject.material.SetFloatArray(materialModifier.identifier, materialModifier.valueFloat);
                    materialModifier.valueFloat = materialModifier.oldValueFloat;
                }
                break;
```

etc etc

```
        }
    }
}
```

(Also your code looks like it might not do exactly what you want... but I haven't changed what it does, because I don't know what you want it to do)

Comment: I left a response in the main post, didn't have enough room. Thanks for reply though, I'm not sure what Switch/Case does, but I will look into that.

Comment: Yes, reading about switch/case on the net is a good idea. It works a lot like a bunch of if/else statements that all check the same value. If it's really long, it sometimes runs a tiny bit faster too.

Comment: Looked it up, nice and easy. Got the code working but was still way to slow cause of all the Ifs/elses. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to check the type when the selected element changes.

```
enum SupportedTypes
{
    Color,
    Int
}
SupportedTypes selectedType;

void OnEnable()
{
    // If the user still didn't select anything, select Int
    selectedType = SupportedTypes.Int;
    // See below to know what this is
    methodUsedToDrawTheLastPart = DrawIntChooser;
}

// One field for each type
// Not elegant but we don't know the type beforehand
Color colorValue;
int intValue;
// ...

// Delegate defining a method signature: in this case "void XXX(string)"
delegate void SetValue(string propertyId);
// Instance of the delegate: think of it as a pointer to a method
//   with the signature defined earlier
// You can set this field to any method being "void XXX(string)"
SetValue methodUsedToDrawTheLastPart;

// Then One method to draw each property chooser
// They will just draw the last part of the modifier
void DrawColorChooser(string propertyId)
{
    Color newColorValue = EditorGUILayout.ColorField(colorValue);
    if (newColorValue != colorValue)
    {
        colorValue = newColorValue;
        // Replace this with a call to the renderer
        Debug.Log("Set color to " + colorValue);
    }
}
void DrawIntChooser(string propertyId)
{
    int newIntValue = EditorGUILayout.IntField(intValue);
    if (newIntValue != intValue)
    {
        intValue = newIntValue;
        Debug.Log("Set int to " + intValue);
    }
}
// All the other types choosers ...


// Finally, the method to put pieces together
void DrawModifier()
{
    EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
    string propertyId = "propId";
    EditorGUILayout.TextField(propertyId);
    SupportedTypes newModifierType = (SupportedTypes)EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup(selectedType);
    // We only do if-else statements if the type changed
    // So when the user changes only the value, this will be skipped
    if (newModifierType != selectedType)
    {
        // Here, based on the chosen type, we set the delegate
        if (newModifierType == SupportedTypes.Int)
        {
            methodUsedToDrawTheLastPart = DrawIntChooser;
        }
        else if (newModifierType == SupportedTypes.Color)
        {
            methodUsedToDrawTheLastPart = DrawColorChooser;
        }
        selectedType = newModifierType;
    }
    // And then we call it
    methodUsedToDrawTheLastPart(propertyId);
    EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
}
public override void OnInspectorGUI()
{
    DrawModifier();
}
```

Comment: I have a list which holds a custom class in the same script as the code above.

When I click add mod it adds all those drop downs, and text boxes.

I will try that though, I think I'll have to ditch the custom class but its probably for the better.

Edit: Wait, can I get a list to hold different types of variables? Or should I create a list for floats, a list for bools etc...

Thanks.

Comment: I have a list in the script above, which holds a custom class. That class holds floats, float2.34..., and then it holds a bool, int, etc...

When I click add mod it adds all those drop downs, and text boxes.

The user selects which type of variable, float, int bool, but now is the tricky part, when he changes the variables (Not the type, the value), I need it to call a Renderer.material.SetFloat or SetBool etc... Depending on what type of variable, and I just don't know how to do it without doing a bunch of Ifs/elses in a for loop.

Sorry won't let me edit for 5 minutes.

Comment: Ok thanks, yeah it was me who didn't understand the FindTypeByIndex, and couldn't find anything online about it. That will work, so thanks again.
Was kind of hoping for a way to use something like a var, but publicly. But I guess that only compiles, and you can't change what it is at runtime.

Comment: With `FindTypeByIndex` I basically meant the function you pasted in the question. The bunch of if-else statements. You know in which order they are (since you passed the array to `EditorGuiLayout.Popup`) so you can extract the type by the Popup index. Anyway, if the code in the current answer does what you wanted, please mark the question as answered :)

Comment: You don't know how I could get this to work do you? I would have a separate class for each instead, that way, you hit a button, Add Float, add Color. It creates the same thing I had above, but it gets the GUI Layout to draw from script?

public EditorGUILayout DrawMe()
        {
            valueColor = EditorGUILayout.ColorField(valueColor);

            return valueColor;
        }

Is there a way to type code into a string, and then get it to play that string?

Comment: Did you try the code in my answer? Because I think it does exactly what you are asking. I edited it again to make it easy for you to try it. This time the code is complete. You can copy and paste it inside an empty Editor. Just try it and study the part with the `delegate`. If that doesn't answer your question, you will have to be more specific on what you want.

Comment: Yes sorry, I'm using it for my part of the tool thanks.